# Python code not incrementing by specified amount

Tags: python, floating-point, increment

Long story is I'm trying to draw some of the trigonometric graphs, but I'm incrementing a value by 0.1 to get a precise turning point, however when incrementing it's incrementing by 0.100000000006 or some value similar to that, so I'm unable to check if it's equal to another value

I ran a test on a different file to check if the problem was due to some of the sine conversions, incase of a memory leak or something (I'm not sure) and I had the same problem in another file which was just a for loop.

```py
import math
xNum = 0
for x in range(180):
    print(xNum)
    xNum = 0.1 + xNum
```

And when printing xNum I'm getting values like 0.40000000006 that I'm not sure why it isn't incrementing xnum by 0.1. i used xNum += 0.1 but there seems to be no difference in output

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken If you need more precision use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html) or [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fractions.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can read about float point issues in [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

As quick fix to your code, you can use `decimal` module from standard library:

```
from decimal import Decimal

xNum = 0
for x in range(180):
    print(xNum)
    xNum = Decimal('0.1') + xNum
```

This prints:

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
..etc.
```